# Self-collision particles Geometry Nodes - Simulation nodes

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

Could somebody figure out how to detect self-collision on particles created in Geometry Nodes?
I'm using 3.5 alpha-simulation nodes.

[image]

UPDATED(I'm using geometry proximity node and the attribute "close_points" is doing something but not working as expected)

[image]

[image]

Thank you,

Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Proximity node is work for all the instance with same value but if you try raycast it work with different value for each index.

so try with raycast